# Do we have StackExchane or Sports (Beta) as an Application on play store, WMP or on BlackBerry world?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-promotion

I tried to install this site as an App, but I didn't get that. So do we have this site as as App, or if we don't have then can we have this in future. I think this can help us to promote this site.

Comment: SE for Android has just been released: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/?cb=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are Stack Exchange apps that you can find in the App Stores, but I haven't seen any that I like.

Fortunately, Stack Exchange has a mobile version of their sites that work very well.  Just visit sports.stackexchange.com on your mobile browser.  I use it in iOS Safari on my iPod Touch all the time, and it works well.